# fetch select tag values in controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi everyone I am not sure how to use select tag in view and fetch selected values in controller in rails. I have tried something but not getting result. Please someone help me. Thanks in advance.

index.html.erb

```
    <%=form_for :law, url: display_lawyers_path do |l|%>

      <h3>Enter the Location</h3>
      <%= l.select(:loc,  options_for_select(@city.collect {|c| [c.Location, c.id]}))%>

      <h3>Enter the Service</h3>
      <%= l.select(:ser, options_for_select(@service.collect{|s| [s.Service_Name, s.id]}))%>

      <div>
        <%= l.submit :submit %>
      </div>

  <%end%>
```

lawyers_controller

```
def index
  @city = Lawyerscitylist.select(:Location).uniq
  @service = Lawyersservicelist.select(:Service_Name).uniq
end

def display
  @loc =  params[:law][:loc]
  render text: @loc
end
```

Comment: What is your actual problem?

Comment: Im getting blank screen when i do "render text :@loc". I'm expecting the location which is selected.